# What POOP frameworks exist for Lisp and Scheme

Tags: prototype, object, lisp, scheme, clos

What nice POOP (Prototype-based Object-oriented Programming) Frameworks
exist in Lisp and Scheme?

I know one: Sheeple

But are there any others?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There should be quite a few.

[ObjectLisp](http://lispm.dyndns.org/documentation/ObjectLisp-Manual.pdf) is one. It was used on the LMI Lisp Machines and for the early Macintosh Common Lisp starting in the mid 80s.

Basically every '[Frame system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_language)' without classes can support Prototype-based Object-oriented Programming. There should something like twenty systems that should do it.

Comment: I need to work with Common Lisp perticularly SBCL, where CLOS extensively used, So I am searching some system with CLOS, Common Lisp, MOP. How MOP is compared to ObjectLisp. Is something exist here, where base is POOP over which CLOS framework developed or could be developed as POOP should be natural superset of Class base Object Orientation

Answer (score 5):

*Prometheus* is Self-like prototype system for Scheme (and Racket).